# What does the "|=" operator do in C#?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

I've recently come across some code that I don't fully understand. Below is a basic representation of this code:

```
bool flag = false;
flag |= someFunction();
```

In this example, `someFunction()` is a function that returns a `bool` value. My question is, what does the `|`= operator do?

I haven't found much information regarding `|=` on the web or in this community. I understand basic assignment operations using the `=` operator, comparison operations using the `=`= operator or the other variants, but I've never seen `|=` used in an assignment before.

I also know that the `|` operator is used for a bitwise inclusive `OR` comparison. However, it doesn't make sense to me to use this as part of an assignment. In sudo code it seems that the code above is saying "If the result of a bitwise inclusive OR between "flag" and `someFunction()` results in a true value, assign the true value to flag. Otherwise, assign the value of false to flag." Of course, if either flag or `someFunction()` stored/returned a true value then the result would be true (based on how a bitwise inclusive OR works).

Is this a correct interpretation? If that is how `|=` works, since I know that "flag" is false does it really make any sense to use the `|=` operator as opposed to a simple `=` assignment operator in this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like you know how `|` work, you must know how `+=` work, `|=` means `flag = flag | someFunction()`.... just that simple

Comment: Yes, it’s redundant if `flag` is definitely `false`, but if you use a bunch in a row then it’s not.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. This reassures me that my initial interpretation was correct.  I don't see the need to downvote the question since it hasn't been asked in this community before and the interpretation isn't obvious at first.

Comment: _since I know that "flag" is false does it really make any sense to use the |= operator as opposed to a simple = assignment operator in this scenario?_ You can do it but note that these kind of operators are usually used inside loop and flag value changes over iterations. but here since you set false to bool right after you declare it then `|=` is  useless.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I'll revise the code I'm working on to ensure this is implemented appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flag |= someFunction()` is equivalent to `flag = flag | someFunction();` 
This is the OR assignment operator.

Please see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `=` would have the same effect in your case.

In general, if there are several such conditions, the first one may use `|=` simply for consistency, but it has no technical advantage here.